# Canvas draws artifacts in Safari for animated, filled bezier curves

Tags: html, canvas, safari, artifact

I created an animated HTML5 canvas that uses bezier curves to draw a filled pattern.

I have been testing it in Chrome for Mac. I only seem to see this on Safari for Mac.

For some reason, I see little artifacts left behind by the figures (see below that is moving to the left and the artifacts go off to the right).

[image: artifacts]

I trigger a redraw by changing the width of the canvas to its current width, if that helps...

Also, if I mouse over the canvas or change windows the artifacts go away. Since I think it decides to redraw the whole thing over.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: That's interesting. Can we see the code for it?

Comment: Yes, you can see it here: http://pescebarsf.com. It is part of a Wordpress theme, but I doubt that has anything to do with it... Thanks.

Comment: i just wonder when seeing this if you do call beginPath() on each new path. this is a common mistake, that always leads to strange behaviors.

Comment: The author forgot about the question, doesn't answer question and will never do.

Comment: Correct, the site that this was originally on (about 3 years ago) has now changed. There is apparently no answer for this question... :-P