# D3.js Ghosts / Artifacts on Safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, safari, webkit

It's my first use of D3.js but I encounter a bug on Safari.
When I load the page, there is some artifacts at the end of the animation.
If I try to resize the window or do anything with the web inspector, the artifacts disapear.

I've already looked for any similar posts and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423756/svg-animations-artifacts-on-safari) which is pretty old but seems really similar to my issue.  I've found it seems linked to this [webkit issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74002) and tested in this [test case](http://www.mysparebrain.com/svgbug.html) but it has been solved and the test case does not seem to be buggy on Safari anymore.

According to this post I tried to use this [patch](https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=118452&action=edit) to move the svg element after loading but without any positive effect

I also tried to create svg and g elements myself without append and use javascript only to set correct attributes but without any positive effect neither.

Does anyone have any idea why and how to fix it ?

Code

```
var svg = d3.select(container)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "d-block mx-auto mt-2")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+(width/2)+","+(height/2)+")");
```

Capture
[image]